# Caching issue: ascx/usercontrol's programmatic Page.Title ignored during cached load of page

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, ascx

The problem is:  When a user vists Default.aspx, the page loads the cached version of the Blog.ascx content (because it has hit the same page again within 600 seconds), the Page.Title code is not executed therefore the title remains empty instead of having `<title>Title of Blog Post</title>` like when it freshly loads the page the first time.

---

My asp.net website has Blog.ascx to handle loading the content of an individual blog post. Default.aspx contains the reference to and uses the Blog.ascx
The Blog.ascx page has custom caching:

```
    <%@ OutputCache Duration="600" VaryByParam="None" VaryByCustom="Url" %>
```

The custom caching, located at global.asax.cs is:

```
    public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string custom)
    {
        switch (custom.ToUpper())
        {
            case "URL":
                return context.Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().Trim();
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

The Blog.ascx.cs  Page_Load event handles the programmatic  tag's value/content

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.Title = "Title of Blog Post";
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can not avoid that issue - you need to redesign your idea to make it work, either remove the cache, either save the title on main page, either make custom cache of your render.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using UserControls?
If you created a UserControl for the content of you page, you could move the OutputCache declaration to the control, thus freeing up the Page_Load event to set the Page title every visit.

Comment: If I understand your comment correctly, you are suggesting the same thing I'm already doing?

Comment: I missed that completely. Sorry.
An option would be to use a public variable set by the UserControl, that is then referenced by some javascript: document.title = '<%variable%>';

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't an option either because search engines / crawlers would still see an empty Title, Javascript would only resolve the display to the end user

Comment: Control in the header of the page, with the same functionality? Which then outputs the PageTitle from server side code.